# Is there a way to test nested objects without the web or persistence layer in Spring Boot?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, junit, mockito

I'm using JUnit5 to test a Spring Boot application. I want to test a `@Service` object, which uses `@Autowired` fields. I would like to mock another `@Service` object which is indirectly used by my test object. Concretely, I have the following (highly simplified) setup:

Object being tested:

```
@Service
public class MainService {
    
    private @Autowired SubService subService;
    
    public String test() {
        return subService.test();
    }

}
```

`SubService`:

```
@Service
public class SubService {
    
    private @Autowired StringService stringService;

    public String test() {
        return stringService.test();
    }

}
```

`StringService`:

```
@Service
public class StringService {

    public String test() {
        return "Real service";
    }

}
```

Test class used:

```
@SpringBootTest
public class MainServiceTest {

    private @Autowired MainService mainService;
    private @MockBean StringService stringService;
    
    @BeforeEach
    public void mock() {
        Mockito.when(stringService.test()).thenReturn("Mocked service");
    }
    
    @Test
    public void test() {
        assertEquals("Mocked service", mainService.test());
    }
    
}
```

The above works if I run the test class as a `@SpringBootTest`, but this loads the full application and is very slow. I also want to avoid `@WebMvcTest` since I don't need the web server, or `@DataJpaTest` since I don't need persistence. I don't want to mock `SubService`, as it contains functionality I want to test together with the `MainService`.

I tried the following:

- `@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)` => throws `NoSuchBeanDefinitionException`, it seems the autowiring does not work in this case
- `@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)` and using `@InjectMocks` and `@Mock` instead of the Spring annotations => as the `StringService` is not a direct field of the `MainService` being tested, this does not work.

Is there a way to use the spring dependency injection system without loading the web server or persistence layer, or alternatively not use Spring tests but allow for 'nested' dependency injection?

Comment: Which class are you trying to test? Why can't you mock SubService when testing the MainService and write unit tests for SubService separately?

Comment: @msfoster I'm testing MainService. Technically I can mock SubService, but I prefer not to, as it doesn't make a lot of sense in the underlying implmentation (the mock would just be a copy of the code in SubService).

Comment: The Stubs Are simple, suited for the test case. Why would you copy the implementation?

Comment: If you provide an example of a method you'd like to test it's easier to hjelp you :)

Comment: I see you already use Mockito dependency for your test and you want to avoid `SpringBootTest`, why not then use Mockito's @Mock and @InjectMock to just unit test what you need?

Comment: @msfoster I'm not sure what you mean with the stubs are simple. The code I provided is a highly simplified version of the actual code I'm using. `SubService` contains a lot of complex code that is required to test `MainService`.

Comment: @ManishKarki As I've written in my question, I tried to do this, but it does not work. `@InjectMock` only inserts `@Mock` used directly, not indirect (fields used by fields). Or is there a way to make this indirect mocking work in mockito?

Comment: @msfoster I"ve included the code of the test case, which tests the method `test()` in `MainService`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use profiling (i.e Spring `@Profile`) to avoid loading the whole application. It will look something like below:

```
@Profile("test")
@Configuration
public class TestConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public MainService mainService() {
        return new MainService();
    }

    @Bean
    public SubService subService() {
        return new SubService();
    }
    // mock the StringService
    @Bean
    public StringService stringService() {
        return Mockito.mock(StringService.class);
    }
 
}
```

then use that profile with `@SpringBootTest(classes = TestConfiguration.class), it will look something like below:

```
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@SpringBootTest(classes = TestConfiguration.class)
class MainServiceTest {

    @Autowired
    private MainService mainService;

    @Test
    public void test() {
        // configure behavior using apis like when(), basically however you 
        // want your mock to behave
    }

}
```

This will load only the beans defined in the class `TestConfiguration`.
NOTE: Since your question is more about how to avoid loading the whole application, I've answered focusing on that. The above approach will get the job done, but I'd prefer constructor wiring over any other mode of dependency injection on any given day, it's easier to maintain and test(like cases where you want to mock).